# Seamless compilation on file change on Visual Studio for Mac (ASP .Net Core)

Tags: asp.net-core, visual-studio-mac

When compiling a ASP .Net Core project without debugging in Visual Studio for Windows, subsequent changes to C# files trigger a new seamless compilation when reloading the website.

I tried it under VS Mac, but unfortunately it does not work. I either have to manually recompile the project, which open an unnecessary new browser window or lauch the command line "dotnet watch run" but it runs a compilation each time a file change an not each time I reload the website and there is at least 1 file change.

Is there a way to achieve the same behavior of VS Win or is it a feature of IIS Express?

Comment: Any luck on this ? Trying to solve the same issue. Thanks

Comment: Unfortunately, no.